# How to make this KNN code faster in google colab or any other ipython based environment?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, google-colaboratory, knn

I am using google colaboratory for KNN classification of DonorsChoose dataset. When I am applying KNeighbors classifier for the avgw2v and tfidf datasets, the following code takes around 4 hours to execute.

I have already tried running it on kaggle notebooks, still the issue persists.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
train_auc_set3 = []
cv_auc_set3 = []
K = [51, 101]
for i in tqdm(K):
    neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=i, n_jobs=-1)
    neigh.fit(X_tr_set3, y_train)

    y_train_set3_pred = batch_predict(neigh, X_tr_set3)    
    y_cv_set3_pred = batch_predict(neigh, X_cr_set3)        
    train_auc_set3.append(roc_auc_score(y_train,y_train_set3_pred))
    cv_auc_set3.append(roc_auc_score(y_cv, y_cv_set3_pred))

plt.plot(K, train_auc_set3, label='Train AUC')
plt.plot(K, cv_auc_set3, label='CV AUC')

plt.scatter(K, train_auc_set3, label='Train AUC points')
plt.scatter(K, cv_auc_set3, label='CV AUC points')

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel("K: hyperparameter")
plt.ylabel("AUC")
plt.title("ERROR PLOTS")
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Comment: what is the shape of X_tr_set3 ?

Comment: There is KNN on CUDA which should run orders of magnitude faster

Answer (score 0):

This may be inherently slow. I'm not terribly familiar with this dataset but glancing at it on Kaggle it looks like it contains over 4 million datapoints. From the sklearn page on KNN:

> For each iteration, time complexity is O(n_components x n_samples >x min(n_samples, n_features)).

Also keep in mind that for a large dataset, knn is going to have to measure the distance between a given datapoint and all datapoints in the training set in order to make a prediction, which is computationally expensive.

Using large numbers on k for a very large dataset you may get very poor performance. What I might do would be to:

1. see how much time fitting knn with a single value of k takes and making predictions for the training set with a single value of k takes. If it takes a long time, then that's your problem as I suspect.

Unfortunately sometimes for very large datasets we are constrained in our choice of algorithm by the time complexity of the algorithms we might like to use. Kernel ridge regression, for example, is a great algorithm that just doesn't scale well to large datasets because it has O(N^3) time complexity.